# How catch the http errors with map

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have coded the guard that access on http api and the http return true|200 or error:unauthorized|401

I can handle guard with http|200 but in map i can't catch the 401 error so how can I catch 401 in `pipe(map())`

my guard code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot , Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsSigninGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private _auth:AuthenticationService, private router:Router ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this._auth.authState().pipe(
      map(status=>{
        if(!status) { this.router.navigate(['/auth/signin']); return false;}
        return true
      })
    )


  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can modify the code in this way:

```
map(status=>{
        if(!status) { this.router.navigate(['/auth/signin']); return false;}
        return true
      }),
catchError((err, caught) => {
          //this you can do what do you want when error
         });
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it's show that error "err' is declared but its value is never read."

Comment: It is correct! you can do "console.log(err)" and I think that it show the error code with error.status;

Comment: that error show up to me after change on code as you said 
Argument of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<boolean>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<boolean>) => ObservableInput<boolean>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<boolean>'.

Comment: if you print "console.log(err.status);" what do you print?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot , Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../services/authentication.service'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IsSigninGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor( private _auth:AuthenticationService, private router:Router ) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this._auth.authState().pipe(
      map(status=>{
        if(!status) { this.router.navigate(['/auth/signin']); return false;}
        return true
      }), catchError(err => {
           console.log(err);
          // Do some stuff with your error and return Empty Obserable.
          return of([]))
         }))    
  }
}
```

More on **catchError** [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html)